# fullcalendar 5.5.1 is not a function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to update from fullcalendar 2.6.1 to fullcalendar 5.5.1 but am getting fullcalendar is not a function error in the console.

You can see version fullcalendar 2.6.1 in the snippet.  If toggle the css and js to switch to version 5.5.1 you can see the problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Extendx FullCalendar Events with Bootstrap Modal</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!--********************toggle this css*************************-->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.css">-->
<!--********************toggle this css*************************-->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>FullCalendar Events with Bootstrap Modal</h1>
                <p>from <a href="http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/fullcalendar-event-details-with-bootstrap-modal/" target="_blank">http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/fullcalendar-event-details-with-bootstrap-modal/</a></p>
                <br />
                <div id="bootstrapModalFullCalendar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                    <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    

<!--********************toggle this js*************************-->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.js"></script>-->
<!--********************toggle this js*************************-->



    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: '',
                    center: 'prev title next',
                    right: ''
                },
                eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                    $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                    $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
                    $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
                    $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                    return false;
                },
                events:
                [
                   {
                      "title":"Free Pizza",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Free Pizza.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().subtract(14,'days'),
                      "end":moment().subtract(14,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/coding-without-music-vs-coding-with-music/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"DNUG Meeting",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the DNUG Meeting.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().subtract(10,'days'),
                      "end":moment().subtract(10,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/youtube-video-event-tracking-with-google-analytics/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"Staff Meeting",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Staff Meeting.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().subtract(6,'days'),
                      "end":moment().subtract(6,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/what-if-your-website-were-an-animal/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"Poker Night",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Poker Night.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().subtract(2,'days'),
                      "end":moment().subtract(2,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/how-to-make-a-qr-code-in-asp-net/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"NES Gamers",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the NES Gamers.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment(),
                      "end":moment(),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/name-that-nes-soundtrack/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"XBox Tourney",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the XBox Tourney.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().add(3,'days'),
                      "end":moment().add(3,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/worst-job-titles-in-internet-and-info-tech/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"Pool Party",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Pool Party.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().add(5,'days'),
                      "end":moment().add(5,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/jquery-full-calendar/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"Staff Meeting",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Staff Meeting.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().add(9,'days'),
                      "end":moment().add(9,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/keep-important-licensing-comments-dotnet-bundling-minification/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"Poker Night",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Poker Night.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().add(11,'days'),
                      "end":moment().add(11,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/aspnet-bundling-changes-output-with-user-agent-eureka-1/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"Hackathon",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Hackathon.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                       "start":moment().add(15,'days'),
                      "end":moment().add(15,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/worst-job-titles-in-internet-and-info-tech/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"Beta Testing",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Beta Testing.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().add(22,'days'),
                      "end":moment().add(22,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/worst-job-titles-in-internet-and-info-tech/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"Perl Meetup",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Perl Meetup.</p><p>Nothing to see... though no one would show up any way.</p>",
                      "start":moment().subtract(20,'days'),
                      "end":moment().subtract(20,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/migrating-from-asp-net-to-ghost-node-js/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"Node.js Meetup",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Node.js Meetup.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().add(25,'days'),
                      "end":moment().add(25,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/pdf-secure-access-and-log-downloads/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"Javascript Meetup",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the Javascript Meetup.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().subtract(27,'days'),
                      "end":moment().subtract(27,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/migrating-from-asp-net-to-ghost-node-js/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"HTML Meetup",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the HTML Meetup.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().subtract(22,'days'),
                      "end":moment().subtract(22,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/migrating-from-asp-net-to-ghost-node-js/"
                   },
                   {
                      "title":"CSS Meetup",
                      "allday":"false",
                      "description":"<p>This is just a fake description for the CSS Meetup.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
                      "start":moment().add(27,'days'),
                      "end":moment().add(27,'days'),
                      "url":"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/migrating-from-asp-net-to-ghost-node-js/"
                   }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a totally different major version that's expected to have many breaking changes, including the way to initialize the widget, refer to their documentation to see the needed changes to follow for the new version

Comment: @Zac, the documentation is in no way helpful.  Do you know how to do this? Where exactly in the docs would you look?

Comment: I don't use it, but from Docs of different versions, starting from Version 4 it's clear that there's no more use of `.fullCalendar()` that was used in [version 3](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/initialization) and earlier versions, instead, you need to use it like: `new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElement, { ..... });` in [version 5](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals)

Comment: @Zac, thanks that did the trick

Comment: You might also want to read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3 and then https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4 (the first one is the major chunk, but there are some bits and pieces changed from 4 to 5 as well, so you get a cumulative picture). There's some _very_ useful documentation on fullCalendar's site, if you take the time.

Answer (score 2):

Fullcalender supports since 4.x no jQuery any more.

So

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({  ...
```

would not work any more.

Replace it by

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var calendarEl = document.getElementById('bootstrapModalFullCalendar'); 
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { ...
```

But of cause you can use JQuery inside your functions.

Also a lot of other things change. But a short look on the rest of your code tells me, that you  didn't use anything of if. So, if you have look, that's all.